# Significato di "m'inorecchii" in questo brano

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Ebbene, avevo appena cominciato a salire l'infima scaletta, che mi parve udire un
>   leggerissimo scalpiccio in cima a questa. Di nuovo il vecchio o,
>   peggio ancora, i suoi cani, spintisi per un caso fin lì? **M'inorecchii**: sembrava pesta umana, benché non di persona in babbucce.
>   E se non il vecchio, di bel nuovo, chi?

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "inorecchiarsi" in questo brano? Ho cercato "inorecchiare" e "inorecchiarsi" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questi vocaboli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non conosco questo verbo (e suppongo dal contesto che significhi qualcosa come “mettersi sul chi vive”), ma dal punto di vista formale, se il passato remoto è “inorecchii”, l'infinito dovrebbe essere “inorecchire” (che in effetti è presente in [questo dizionario amatoriale](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=INORECCHIRE100) in cui non ripongo particolare fiducia).

Google ne rinviene almeno un uso all'interno di *Il cavalier Mostardo* di Antonio Beltramelli, risalente agli anni '20:

> E udiva, così stando e in tanta tristezza, il ronzio delle vespe, delle mosche, dei calabroni. Poi avvertì che qualcuno parlava dietro le sue spalle ; ma non vi pose mente ; **solo un nome lo fece inorecchire**. Certo i due conversatori non l' avevano veduto e parlavano abbastanza forte perchè non sfuggisse a lui una sola parola.

E dal contesto è chiaro anche qui che il verbo significa “richiamare l'attenzione”.

A conferma, il Treccani riporta [“inorecchito”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inorecchito), nel senso di “Stando con le orecchie tese, attento: *e riguardava intorno, inorecchita* (Pascoli)”.

Comment: Interessante anche la formazione di questo verbo, con l’uso del prefisso in- preposto al sostantivo “orecchio” (cfr. il secondo significato qui: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/in-prefisso_(La-grammatica-italiana)/).

Comment: Si utilizzano anche espressioni come "drizzare le orecchie" o "essere tutto orecchi"

Answer (score 0):

Nel contesto da te citato inorecchiarsi significa prestare attenzione a ciò che arriva all'orecchio, ai rumori, origliare.

Su Treccani puoi trovare per [orecchiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/orecchiare/), sinonimo di origliare:

> 1. intr. (aus. avere) Stare in ascolto per sentire, senza essere visto, ciò che altri dicono, o ciò che avviene; origliare: *non è bello
>      stare a o. dietro alle porte; eccomi in cucina, e lì mi fermai in
>      punta di piedi, orecchiando* (F. De Sanctis). Anche come trans., con lo
>      stesso senso: *orecchiava i discorsi dei colleghi con pettegola
>      curiosità*; o con quello di sentire per caso e senza che altri se
>      n’accorga: *a metà della cucina aveva orecchiato la voce del teologo*
>      (I. Nievo).

In senso figurato, considerare le istanze e le richieste di qualcuno.

Dal [Corriere della Sera](http://www.corriere.it/cultura/12_luglio_05/elzeviro-goldoni-non-capisce-antifona_1c061ee2-c688-11e1-8ab7-67e552429064.shtml):

> Intanto una gigantesca congiunzione di antifone si addensa sui cieli
>   d'Italia e d'Europa. La nostra classe politica dovrebbe inorecchiarsi
>   ai tanti fenomeni che la riguardano